# Advice on JanusGraph Docker Image Startup Scripts

Tags: docker, janusgraph

I would like to have an idempotent startup script which initializes my database. In particular, I would like to define the schema (labels, properties, indexes, and constraints). I am using JanusGraph inside of a Docker container, and I am required to frequently teardown/rebuild from the container image. I have a very sloppy working approach, but I have been unable to improve upon it.

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65538732/how-to-import-data-into-janusgraph-docker-at-startup) question, but my use case is different since I am trying to configure the database, rather than simply load data. I have also read the section of the JanusGraph [documentation on using](https://docs.janusgraph.org/operations/container/#initialization) `.groovy` scripts to populate data, but similarly this doesn't cover my use case. As defined in the [section on defining a schema](https://docs.janusgraph.org/schema/), I would like to create labels/properties/indexes/constraints, and I want this to be done automatically when the database starts.

My current setup is very poor. I connect to the JanusGraph instance similarly to how you do in the Gremlin console with `:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml`. Below is my current setup:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  btc_janus:
    build:
      context: ./janusgraph/
    container_name: btc_janus
    shm_size: 2g
    ports:
      - "${JANUSGRAPH_PORT:-8182}:${JANUSGRAPH_PORT:-8182}"
      - "8484:8184"
      - "8081:8081"
    networks:
      - btc-network
    volumes:
      - ${GRAPH_DB_FOLDER:-./data/btc_janus}:/var/lib/janusgraph
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "bin/gremlin.sh", "-e", "scripts/remote-connect.groovy"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 60s
      retries: 4
    environment:
      janusgraph.storage.backend: berkeleyje
      janusgraph.tx.log-tx: true
      janusgraph.tx.max-commit-time: 100000000000
```

```
#  ./janusgraph/Dockerfile

FROM janusgraph/janusgraph:latest

ENV JAVA_OPTS=" -Xss4096k "
ENV JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xss4096k"
ENV JVM_OPTS="-Xss4096k"

# Copy the index creation script
COPY create_index.groovy /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_index.groovy
```

```
// ./janusgraph/create_index.groovy

:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml
:remote console

:> graph.tx().rollback(); mgmt = graph.openManagement(); idKey = mgmt.containsPropertyKey('output_id') ? mgmt.getPropertyKey('output_id') : mgmt.makePropertyKey('output_id').dataType(Integer.class).make(); addressKey = mgmt.containsPropertyKey('address_id') ? mgmt.getPropertyKey('address_id') : mgmt.makePropertyKey('address_id').dataType(Integer.class).make(); if (!mgmt.containsGraphIndex('byOutputIdComposite')) { mgmt.buildIndex('byOutputIdComposite', Vertex.class).addKey(idKey).buildCompositeIndex(); }; if (!mgmt.containsGraphIndex('byAddressIdComposite')) { mgmt.buildIndex('byAddressIdComposite', Vertex.class).addKey(addressKey).buildCompositeIndex(); }; mgmt.commit();
```

As you can see, the above approach is very messy. Everything is forced to be on one line. Adding any more schema specifications would be challenging. Is there a better approach to creating JanusGraph startup scripts?